# How to center tkinter label between two x coordinates

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-label

If I have a tkinter window of width 300 and height 500, what code do I use to center a label between the lines of x=100 and x=300?

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('300x500')

label = tkinter.Label(root, text='Test.')

label.place(???)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: `label.place(x=200, rely=0.5, anchor='c')` will put the label at the center between x=100 and x=300 and center vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('300x500')

label = tkinter.Label(root, text='Test.')

label.place(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, relx=.5, rely=.5)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

For easier understanding

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('300x500')
root['background']='white'
label = tkinter.Label(root, text='Test.', width=10, height=10, bg='red')

label.place(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, relx=.5, rely=.5)

tkinter.mainloop()
```